# Building an angular 5 custom module with angular-cli contains predefined routing array

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular5, angular-routing

I ran the following command to create module with separate routing file:

```
$ ng g module xyz --routing
```

this command will create these two files:

- xyz.module.ts
- xyz-routing.module.ts

There is an empty array of routes, Inside the file **xyz-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [];
```

Is there anyway to fill the array automatically, for example with predefined template, array or etc ?

Comment: The array should be statically defined. If you need to fill it programmatically, you need to generate .ts file. This depends on your tools and expected route contents. See https://www.softwarearchitekt.at/post/2017/10/29/generating-custom-code-with-the-angular-cli-and-schematics.aspx for possible CLI approach

Comment: Suppose that I will add its components automatically.

Comment: Well ... technically you *could* have it do this. You could build your own schema for the Angular CLI to use and add to that schema the specific set of routes you want populated in that array. But it would seem to be a lot of work vs simply typing the routes into the array. You could also use a schema and modify the `ng g c xxx` so that every component you add would have an entry added to the routes array. But it would not know the route name or its place in the hierarchy.

Comment: @DeborahK, that would make for a 5 hour PluralSight course just to learn how to do that! Who has the time!? :)

Comment: :-) The Angular team just wrote a detailed blog post about it: https://blog.angular.io/schematics-an-introduction-dc1dfbc2a2b2

Comment: @DeborahK thanks for your advice. finally I built a bash script to create a crud package automatically :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in the link Debora shared in comments, I ran the following commands:

```
npm install -g @angular-devkit/schematics-cli

schematics blank --name=crud-module

cd crud-module
npm install
```

Then I changed the name of the package in `crud-module/package.json` to `crud-module`

And I changed the file `crud-module/src/collection.json`:

```
{
  "$schema": "../node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/collection-schema.json",
  "schematics": {
    "crud-module": {
      "description": "A blank schematic.",
      "factory": "./crud-module/index#crudModule"
    }
  }
}
```

The remaining part was modifying the file, `crud-module/src/crud-module/index.ts` :

```
import { Rule, SchematicContext, Tree } from '@angular-devkit/schematics';


// You don't have to export the function as default. You can also have more than one rule factory
// per file.
export function crudModule(options: any): Rule {
  return (tree: Tree, _context: SchematicContext) => {
    var ucFirstName = options.name.substr(0,1).toUpperCase() + options.name.substr(1);
    console.log("ucFirstName", ucFirstName);
    tree.create(`src/app/components/`+options.name+`/`+options.name+'.module.ts', `import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { `+ucFirstName+`Service } from './`+options.name+`.service';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild([
        {
          component: List`+ucFirstName+`Component,
          path: '',
        },
        {
          component: Add`+ucFirstName+`Component,
          path: 'add',
        },
        {
            component: Edit`+ucFirstName+`Component,
            path: 'edit/:id',
        },
    ]),
    CommonModule,
  ],
  declarations: [],
  providers: []
})
export class `+ucFirstName+`Module { }`);
    return tree;
  };
}
```

Then I replaced this command:

```
ng g module MODULE_NAME
```

with this command :

```
schematics  ./crud-module:crud-module --name=MODULE_NAME --dry-run=false
```

And my customized module created :)

Answer (score 0):

Can use this link to understand [angular schematics](https://blog.angular.io/schematics-an-introduction-dc1dfbc2a2b2) and create your components , services and module with it.

Schematics Collections are sets of named schematics, that are published and installed by users. For example, the Angular team publishes and maintains the official @schematics/angular collection, which contains schematics like component, module and application.